# Displaying a web page as a pdf with click of a button

Tags: asp.net, telerik, pdf-generation, itext, html

I have a new requirement to have a button in my web page, and upon clicking, it displays the web page as a PDF. On researching I found that `iTextSharp` is used for such purpose.
But I have many `Telerik` and ASP controls in my web page too. Can I get that also in the PDF using `iTextSharp`?

If yes then can anyone please provide me a basic link to start using `iTextSharp` as I haven't came across this tool yet.

According to the answer from @ahaliav I tried with the following code. However, I'm not getting the controls on the pdf.

```
    protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

        MemoryStream msOutput = new MemoryStream();
        TextReader reader = new StringReader(HtmlContent);

        // step 1: creation of a document-object
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 30, 30);
        HTMLWorker worker = new HTMLWorker(document);
        // step 2:
        // we create a writer that listens to the document
        // and directs a XML-stream to a file
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);

        // step 3: we create a worker parse the document

        // step 4: we open document and start the worker on the document
        document.Open();
        worker.StartDocument();

        // step 5: parse the html into the document
        worker.Parse(reader);

        // step 6: close the document and the worker
        worker.EndDocument();
        worker.Close();
        document.Close();
        //Response.Write(document);
        //Response.End();

    }
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        // setup a TextWriter to capture the markup
        TextWriter tw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

        // render the markup into our surrogate TextWriter
        base.Render(htw);

        // get the captured markup as a string
        string pageSource = tw.ToString();

        // render the markup into the output stream verbatim
        writer.Write(pageSource);

        // remove the viewstate field from the captured markup
        HtmlContent = Regex.Replace(pageSource,
            "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"__VIEWSTATE\" id=\"__VIEWSTATE\" value=\".*?\" />",
            "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        // the page source, without the viewstate field, is in viewStateRemoved
        // do what you like with it

    }
```

Please help .
I have other option also,that is to display the image of the full web page when i click a button.Can anyone guide me to any possible directions for these two issues please.

I finally changed my code as:

```
        Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.doc");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        MemoryStream msOutput = new MemoryStream();
```

With this i am able to get the msword document containing all my controls ,but i am also getting some unwanted texts,how can i remove that,if anyone encountered the same problem?

Comment: I am using [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) in one of my projects to generate a PDF based on a webpage.

Comment: can i get the telerik controls also in that pdf

Comment: Not sure, but my guess would be no.

Comment: I have further modified my question,please help with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research i did not find any solution for showing the controls in the html this code below works fine but with out showing the controls,
in the past i used this http://www.winnovative-software.com/ and it works good for html pages including all controlls you can also test it onlie, the "only" problem is it you need to pay for the license

```
protected void btnExportToPdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        renderPDF = true;
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {           
        if (renderPDF == true)
        {
            MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
            StreamWriter twr = new StreamWriter(mem);
            HtmlTextWriter myWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(twr);
            base.Render(myWriter);
            myWriter.Flush();
            myWriter.Dispose();
            StreamReader strmRdr = new StreamReader(mem);
            strmRdr.BaseStream.Position = 0;
            string pageContent = strmRdr.ReadToEnd();
            strmRdr.Dispose();
            mem.Dispose();
            writer.Write(pageContent);
            CreatePDFDocument(pageContent);
        }
        else
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            HtmlTextWriter tw = new HtmlTextWriter(new System.IO.StringWriter(sb));
            base.Render(tw);
            // get the captured markup as a string
            string pageSource = tw.ToString();
            //Get the rendered content
            string sContent = sb.ToString();
            //Now output it to the page, if you want
            writer.Write(sContent);
        }
    }

    public void CreatePDFDocument(string strHtml)
    {


        string strHTMLpath = Server.MapPath("MyHTML.html");
        StreamWriter strWriter = new StreamWriter(strHTMLpath, false, Encoding.UTF8);
        strWriter.Write(strHtml);
        strWriter.Close();
        string strFileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("map1.pdf"); //    strFileName    "C:\\Inetpub\\wwwroot\\Test\\map1.pdf" 
        // step 1: creation of a document-object
        Document document = new Document();
        // step 2:
        // we create a writer that listens to the document
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.Create));
        StringReader se = new StringReader(strHtml);
        TextReader tr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("MyHTML.html"));

        //add the collection to the document
        document.Open();                        
        /////////
        iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker worker = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(document);

        worker.StartDocument();

        //// step 5: parse the html into the document
        worker.Parse(tr);

        //// step 6: close the document and the worker
        worker.EndDocument();

        //worker.Parse(tr); // getting error "Illegal characters in path"
        document.Close();
        ShowPdf(strFileName);
    }
    public void ShowPdf(string strFileName)
    {
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + strFileName);
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.WriteFile(strFileName);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Clear();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple Google search brings us to the following forum thread which has your "sollution":
http://forums.asp.net/t/1039486.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

iTextSharp comes with a little companion : [XML Worker](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/xmlworker/)

For a demo, have a look [here](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/)

Even though the [documentation](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/index.html) refers to the Java API, the adaptation to C# should be straightforward.

As for Telerik/ASP tags, you can extend XMLWorker and define how to convert such tags into PDF elements.

Comment: I have further modified my question,please help with that

Comment: You added a new question to the original one. You should have created a new question for that.

Comment: Sorry about that ,but can u please help me with that.I will post a new question

Comment: Here is my new question- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445049/converting-web-page-to-word-and-then-to-pdf-in-asp-net